# How to use inotifywait to wait till a file is created and is written content with timeout

Tags: inotify

I'm using shell command in redhat ubi-minimal. I want to monitor a file "./hello.txt", which does not exist yet. I want to use `inotifywait` to monitor this file, and wait until either `./hello.txt` is created and being written some non-empty content in it, or a fixed timeout.

Following [`inotifywait`'s man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait), I tried:

```
inotifywait -m -e create -r --fromfile ./hello.txt -t 30
```

with `-m -e create` specifying that this command executes indefinitely until `create` occur.

But it only gives:

```
Couldn't open ./hello.txt: No such file or directory
No files specified to watch!
```

I wonder how to specify the flags of inotifywait to achieve what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot wait for `./hello.txt` because it doesn't exist yet, so the kernel has no node to attach the inotify object to.

You need to wait on the parent directory (`.`).
The problem is that you have to find a way to filter out only the specific file.
If you have at least version 3.20.1 of `inotifywait`, you can just use the option `--include` to pass a regex with the name of your file.
If you don't, ...well, you can try to use the option `--exclude` and write a reversed regex or you can write a script to filter the result externaly. Both of these options are rather inconvenient.
Answers to this question describe various ways of making the filter: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323901/133542.

If you have the new version, the command will look like this:

```
inotifywait -e close_write -t 30 --include 'hello\.txt' .
```

A few remarks:

- Flags `-m` and `-t` are not allowed together (at least in my version). However, you're waiting for a single specific event so there is no need for `-m`.
- In your code, you're waiting for the event `create` but you've stated that you want to know when the file is written. I've changed the event to `close_write` which means that the file is being closed after being opened in writable mode.
- The flag `--fromfile` means that the file contains a list of files to be watched, not that it is being watched itself. I've removed the flag.
- The flag `-r` is necessary only if you want to watch an entire tree of directories. If the file is directly in the watched directory, you don't need it.

Comment: Notice there seems to be a bug with `--include` and `--includei` where it ignores relevant files if new directories are created while it's watching the parent directory. See the open [Github issue](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/issues/168)

Comment: yes not allowing `-t` in monitor mode is a pain, ideally it would emit a timeout event text but a workaround can be to `while read -t TMO ...; do ...; done < <(inotifywait -qm ...)`